# Table row keeps original height after zooming image (using CSS) in cell (in firefox)

Tags: css, firefox

I have a simple HTML table, where one column contains images. I zoom them using

```
style="zoom: 31%; -moz-transform: scale(0.31); -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;"
```

In Chrome, for example, it works fine. Table looks as expected. In firefox, however, table row keeps its original height - as if there was no zoom applied.

CSS is not my primary expertise, so it may be a simple problem. I tried to applie all the possible values to table row "height" attribute, but nothing had any impact.

Comment: You can always check https://caniuse.com for browser support. `zoom` is not supported in Firefox currently: https://caniuse.com/css-zoom.  If you provide some HTML and a working code snippet, I can do my best to help you solve your problem.

Comment: @SigurdMazanti thank you. I know zoom is not supported, that's why there is ```-moz-transform``` part.

Comment: @SigurdMazanti I prepared a snippet here: https://jsfiddle.net/sbd71ozv/ . Open it in chrome and firefox and see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the columns sizing are defined already in the examples below:

### **Solution 1** - `background-image` on parent

This solution is if you don't have access to the HTML. It simply uses the `background-image`-property on the `td`-element, and makes the `background-image` cover up the entire space of the `td`-element. You can adjust the `background-position` to your liking: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position

```css
td {
  /* Fixed sizing for demo */
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

table,
td {
  overflow: hidden;
}

td.bg-img {
  background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/640x360');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Solution 1</h1>
<table>
  <tr style="background-color: red">
    <td></td>
    <td class="bg-img"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

### **Solution 2** - `background-image` on child

This solution is similiar to the one above, but has the `background-image` attached to another child element of the `td`-element. `width: 100%;` + `height: 100%;` lets the child element take the full size of its parent element. By then applying `transform: scale(1.31);`, the element will be zoomed in (by 31%), and with `overflow: hidden;` applied to `td` and `table`, the images zoom effect is visible and there is no overflow pre.

```css
td {
  /* Fixed sizing for demo */
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

table,
td {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img-child {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/640x360");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  transform: scale(1.31);
}
```

```html
<h1>Solution 2</h1>
<table>
  <tr style="background-color: red">
    <td></td>
    <td class="img">
      <div class="img-child"></div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

### **Solution 3** - `img`-element

If you have access to the HTML or if you care about semantic value, this solution uses the `img`-element. Similiar to the ones above, but uses `object-fit` + `object-position` instead of `background`. You can also adjust the `object-position` to your liking: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position

```css
td {
  /* Fixed sizing for demo */
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

table,
td {
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* Solution 3 */

.img-src {
  display: flex;
}

.img-src img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center center;
  transform: scale(1.31);
}
```

```html
<h1>Solution 3</h1>
<table>
  <tr style="background-color: red">
    <td></td>
    <td class="img-src"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/640x360"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. Unfortunately, it does not work. Parent element, which is TR in this case, still keeps its original height.

I only tried the 3rd solution, since I need the zoom effect to work not only on images, but also on other content (some text) - in case the image is not there.

Note: I'm zooming out, not in. Replace your scale value to 0.31 and you will see.